# How to create a footer that is always visible?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to create a sticky footer but it's not working. I want the footer to always be visible no matter where the user has scrolled on my page

[I want the version on the left, I'm getting the right however](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9bjN.png)

**CSS**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You have to use **fixed** instead of **absolute**.
Check this link [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) , it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

position: fixed

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/gyszqx99/

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie placerat ligula. Vivamus tempus mauris enim, pellentesque vehicula augue bibendum vel. Phasellus et ultrices risus, maximus posuere sapien. Vestibulum et condimentum nisl, sed facilisis turpis. Vivamus suscipit ultricies lorem et imperdiet. Aliquam ut semper ante, nec aliquet arcu. Phasellus ut magna et dolor hendrerit pulvinar sed vitae erat. Morbi ultrices tristique tristique. Donec sed condimentum risus. Nullam volutpat quam dolor, quis tempor massa ultricies non. Vivamus bibendum dapibus vehicula. Nunc molestie risus in orci lacinia dapibus.</p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  This is the footer
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  background: #f0f;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #090;
  color: #fff;
}
```